# Spark with Java: I want to read complex xml file (mentioned below) and parse it POJO

Tags: java, xml, apache-spark

My XML file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root1>
<Root2>
    <RowType1>
    <InsideRowType1>XXX</InsideRowType1>
    </RowType1> 
    <RowType2>
        <InsideRowType2>
            <InnerElement>XXX</InnerElement>
        </InsideRowType2>
    </RowType2>
    <RowType2>
        <InsideRowType2>XXX</InsideRowType2>
    </RowType2>
    <RowType2>
        <InsideRowType2>XXX</InsideRowType2>
    </RowType2>
</Root2>
</Root1>
```

I tried below code to parse it

```
Encoder<POSLog> pOSLogEncoder = Encoders.kryo(POSLog.class);
Dataset<POSLog> df  = sparkSession.read().format("com.databricks.spark.xml").schema(**StructType Schema**).load(**File Path**).toDF().sqlContext().sql("set spark.sql.caseSensitive=false").as(pOSLogEncoder);
```

But it's throwing some error, then tried this code

```
Dataset<Row> df  = sparkSession.read()
                .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
                .schema(**StructType Schema**)
                .load(**File Path**)
                .toDF();
```

But it returns null in `df.show()`

Please help me out in parsing my xml. Also, please suggest if we can have other optimized way to parse it.